# Save value on stepper SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a stepper:

```
Stepper(value: $timeBetweenMeals, in: 1...10, step: 1) {
                                Text("Time Between Meals: \(timeBetweenMeals, specifier: "%.0f")h")
                                self.settingsUserDefaults = $timeBetweenMeals
                            }
```

That gives me error because I'm trying to set: `self.settingsUserDefaults = $timeBetweenMeals` inside that view. How can I run that logic? I don't have a button, I just want to save that @Published value as the user changes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom Binding, and inside your `set` you can store your value:

```
Stepper(value: Binding<Int>(get: {
    self.timeBetweenMeals
}, set: {
    print($0) // here you can access your value with $0, store it here
    self.timeBetweenMeals = $0
}), in: 1...10, step: 1) {
    Text("Time Between Meals: \(timeBetweenMeals)h")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform other actions when `Stepper` value changes in `onIncrement` and `onDecrement` method not inside of the `label` parameter which is meant to return the `View` of the `Stepper`. Here is an example (Note: this is just an example, you can achieve this in many easier ways too):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timeBetweenMeals: Int
    var body: some View {
        Stepper(value: Binding<Int>(get: {
            self.timeBetweenMeals
        }, set: {
            print($0)
            self.timeBetweenMeals = $0
        }), in: 1...10, step: 1) {
            Text("Time Between Meals: \(timeBetweenMeals)h")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I've updated to a much better approach. Credits to davidev. Also, your specifier seems to be incorrect.